# AttributeError: '_MainProcess' object has no attribute '_exiting'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-2.5

I got an

```
AttributeError: '_MainProcess' object has no attribute '_exiting'
```

from a Python application. Unfortunately this code has to run Python 2.5 and therefore the `processing` module nowadays known as `multiprocessing`. What I was doing is to create a `Process` with a `Queue` and to `put` an item in the queue from the main process. Looking into the `processing.queue` code I can see that a feeder thread is started. This feeder thread will then check `currentProcess()._exiting`, but `currentProcess()` evaluates to a `_MainProcess` which does not have said attribute as can be seen in the `processing.process` module. How to solve this? Is it a bug in `processing`? If yes, can I simply monkeypatch it using `currentProcess()._exiting = False`?

Minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import processing
import processing.queue

class Worker(processing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        processing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = processing.queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        element = self.queue.get()
        print element

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Worker()
    w.start()
    # To trigger the problem, any non-pickleable object is to be passed here.
    w.queue.put(lambda x: 1)
    w.join()
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet that reproduces the error? Also, I really like the word *monkeypatch*. Looking forward to using it soon :)

Comment: I believe there is a right way to do what you want without patching.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y I'm sorry, I had a bit problems with reducing those 3k lines of code to a smaller example. :-/

Comment: @Helmut: In that case we are certainly not talking about a *simple Python application*.

Comment: Now I got a: PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed. (I checked every possible code path to avoid this.) Debugging this is gonna be hard!

Comment: This PicklingError is responsible for causing the AttributeError, so I better invest the time to fix the PicklingError. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to pickle a function in this case, if you really want to do that have a look at this answer: [Is there an easy way to pickle a python function (or otherwise serialize its code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pickle-a-python-function-or-otherwise-serialize-its-code)

otherwise, this works for python 2.6 (I know you are looking for 2.5 but I don't have 2.5). I have replaced your lambda function with a regular function and provide that to the processing constructor:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def simple():
    return 1

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, args):
        Process.__init__(self, args=args)
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        element = self.queue.get()
        print element

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Worker(args=[simple])
    w.start()
    w.join()
```

Comment: I am sorry, but you completely missed the point. The problem is that it is not obvious from the error message that non-pickleable object was passed. The lambda is just an example for a non-pickleable object.

Comment: but that's why i gave you the link to pickle a python function and you can put the pickled function in your queue, and when you get it from your queue then you can reconstruct the function

Comment: You still completely miss the point. The initial problem was the error message. Half of the solution was finding out it was caused by a non-pickleable object. Working around non-pickleable objects is trivial once you know what is the cause. The missing part is to fix the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive comments, I'll help you next time as well.