# Pass client-side function to celery task

Tags: python, celery

I'd like to pass a function the client creates to a celery task and have it be executed. For example below, I'm trying to write a `map` function that takes in a function `f` and a list `l` and do `map(f, l)` in the celery task.

Presumably, the function is not getting serialized correctly (understandable, that's hard). But, is there any way to do this? What's the best practice? I suppose I could pass a string and then `exec` it, but I'd rather not just the way my app is intended to work.

edit: I found a way to [serialize a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pickle-a-python-function-or-otherwise-serialize-its-cod)... I guess I could wrap that up to do what I need to do. Any better ideas?

---

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost', backend='redis://localhost')

@app.task
def cp_map(f, l):
    return map(f, l)
```

Then, I try to use this task with this:

```
In [20]: from tasks import cp_map

In [21]: def f(x): return x + 1

In [22]: cp_map.delay(f, [1,2,3])
Out[22]: <AsyncResult: 27baf8bf-8ef3-496d-a445-ebd7ee94e206>

In [23]: _.status
Out[23]: 'PENDING'
```

On the worker, I get this:

```
[2014-02-09 22:27:00,828: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: DecodeError(AttributeError("'module' object has no attribute 'f'",),) (type:u'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:u'binary' raw:"'\\x80\\x02}q\\x01(U\\x07expiresq\\x02NU\\x03utcq\\x03\\x88U\\x04argsq\\x04c__main__\\nf\\nq\\x05]q\\x06(K\\x01K\\x02K\\x03e\\x86q\\x07U\\x05chordq\\x08NU\\tcallbacksq\\tNU\\x08errbacksq\\nNU\\x07tasksetq\\x0bNU\\x02idq\\x0cU$27baf8bf-8ef3-496d-a445-ebd7ee94e206q\\rU\\x07retriesq\\x0eK\\x00U\\x04taskq\\x0fU\\x0ctasks.cp_mapq\\x10U\\ttimelimitq\\x11NN\\x86U\\x03etaq\\x12NU\\x06kwargsq\\x13}q\\x14u.' (233b)"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 585, in _receive_callback
    decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/message.py", line 142, in decode
    self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 184, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 184, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 64, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
DecodeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use marshal to serialize the function to a string then deserialize it in the task. I don't know if it's the best way, but but it will work. You may also want to look at [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill).

Here is some example code copied from [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253813/426600):

```
import marshal
def foo(x): return x*x
code_string = marshal.dumps(foo.func_code)
```

Then in the task:

```
import marshal, types

code = marshal.loads(code_string)
func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "some_func_name")

func(10)  # gives 100
```

Comment: The 'cloud' library on PyPI contains utilities to serialize a local function and is reportedly working very well.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I instead get an error:

`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may encounter an issue with encoding complex functions. You can either ignore or replace errors during encoding.

```
__ENCODING_FORMAT = 'ISO-8859-1'  # ISO-8859-1 is a work-around to avoid UnicodeDecodeError on 'byte 0x83'

def _serialize_func(func):
    """ converts func into code string and encodes it with ISO-8859-1 """
    return unicode(marshal.dumps(func.func_code), encoding=__ENCODING_FORMAT, errors='replace')


def _load_func(code_string):
    """ loads func from code string, decodes from unicode to str"""
    code = marshal.loads(code_string.encode(__ENCODING_FORMAT))
    return types.FunctionType(code, globals())
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error will also occur if the function you are referencing sits in a file with a __main__ directive, ie: the file containing the function definition looks something like:

```
def f(*args):
    ... some code here ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ... some code here ...
```

If this is the case, having the function definition sit in a file separate from the "__main__" referencing code should solve the problem.

Assuming this simple refactoring is indeed applicable to your use case, it is much simpler than the above marshal jiujitsu.