# execute arbitrary function by celery worker

Tags: python, celery

I have a running celery server using redis as the borker and result storage (python3). I would like to have an arbitrary function, which has not been registered to the server, being executed by a celery worker. I tried to serialize this function using the package [marshal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) (following [Is there an easy way to pickle a python function (or otherwise serialize its code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pickle-a-python-function-or-otherwise-serialize-its-cod)) and transfered the bytecode to a worker:

celery_server.py:

```
from celery import Celery
import types
import marshal

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://localhost')

@app.task
def run_fct( fct_code, args, kwargs ):
    code = marshal.loads( fct.__code__ )
    func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "some_func_name" )

    return fct( *args, **kwargs )
```

client.py

```
from celery_server import run_fct
import marshal

def calc( x, y ):
    return x*y

fct_code = marshal.dumps( calc.func_code )
run_fct.apply_async( (fct_code, 10, 2 ) )
```

I get the following error on the client side:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

in the function `bytes_to_str` in `kombu.utils.encoding.py`.

Is there another or better way to have my function being executed?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: By wrapping my function and giving the wrapped function to the celery task as an argument solves the `UnicodeDecodeError`:

celery_server.py:

```
class MyFunction( object ):
    def __init__(self, fct):
        self.fct_code = marshal.dumps( fct.__code__ )

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        run_fct.apply_async( args=(self,)+args, kwargs=kwargs, serializer='pickle' )
```

and in client.py:

```
from celery_server import MyFunction

myFct = MyFunction( calc )
myFct.run( x=10, y=2 )
```

then it works like a charm.

However, using the package [cloud](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloud) solves also dependency problems of my function on the worker side, for instance, if I used additional functions or packages in my function:

```
from celery import Celery
import cloud
import pickle

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://localhost')

class MyFunction( object ):
    def __init__(self, fct):
        self.serialized_code = cloud.serialization.cloudpickle.dumps(fct)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        run_fct.apply_async( args=(self,)+args, kwargs=kwargs, serializer='pickle' )

@app.task
def run_fct( myFct, *args, **kwargs ):
    fct = pickle.loads( myFct.serialized_code )

    return fct( *args, **kwargs )
```

client.py:

```
from tasks import MyFunction
import time

def calc( x, y ):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x*y

myFct = MyFunction( calc )
myFct.run( x=10, y=2 )
```

BUT: the current [cloud](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloud) does not support python3.