# can't pickle dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, redis, pickle

I have a simple dictionary that i am trying to save to cache and looks like it django is trying to pickle:

```
  podcasts = []
  for i in items:
        s = re.sub('[\s+]', '', str(i))
        s2 = re.findall(r'<link/>(.*?)<itunes',s)[0]

        item_obj = {}
        item_obj['title'] = title
        item_obj['url'] = s2
        item_obj['created_at'] = created_at
        item_obj['duration'] = duration

        podcasts.append(item_obj)
```

This has a very simple format that outputs:

```
[{'title': "Podcast1", 'url': 'https://example.com\\n', 'created_at': 'Thu, 28 Dec 2017', 'duration': '00:30:34'}]
```

I am running this from a custom management command like this:

```
python3 manage.py podcast_job
```

I attempt to save to cache:

```
    podcasts = get_podcasts()
    print(podcasts)
    cache.set('podcasts', podcasts)
```

I get the error:

```
File "podcast_job.py", line 13, in handle
    cache.set('podcasts', podcasts)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 33, in _decorator
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 68, in set
    return self.client.set(*args, **kwargs)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 109, in set
    nvalue = self.encode(value)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 329, in encode
    value = self._serializer.dumps(value)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django_redis/serializers/pickle.py", line 33, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(value, self._pickle_version)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

If I try to save with a string I get no error and it saves fine:

```
   cache.set('podcasts', str(podcasts))
```

How can I save the list of dictionaries and not get the error above?

Comment: Edit your question to show how `item_obj` is initially created.

Comment: This is the second time you’ve asked about this error but I still don’t think you’ve included enough information to reproduce the error. Please show the full management command that isn’t working.

Comment: @Alasdair I guess in python3 cache needs to be stored as json instead of a dictionary?  This solved my problem.  But you are the Python master, you let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `datetime` objects for `created_at` and `duration`, make sure you render them to strings.

Comment: that sounds interesting. Can you elaborate? basically, every object shouldn't be pickled if not necessary.

Comment: A python datetime object contains things that cannot be cast to string or are invokable (such as class methods). It seems like it may be invoking a method such as .now() that returns another datetime object and doing so over and over until it reaches recursion depth.

Answer (score 1):

Pickle does not deal well with functions.

Check out this answer for some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253813/4225229

You could serialize the result of the function (try `json.dumps()`) and cache that.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the dictionary with json as Jacob suggested like this:

```
cache.set('podcasts', json.dumps(podcasts))
```