# Python: Pickle.load function returns the correct 3d-scatter plot, but is not interactive anymore

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pickle, scatter3d

this is my first question here so let me know if I should make any improvements regarding e.g. formulation of the question, code and so on.

So I am creating several 3-D Scatter Plots in Python and want to safe them for later re usage and comparability. I am using Qt5 as Graphics Backend in Spyder, which perfectly displays my interactive (so I can rotate over the axes and flip the plot) 3-D Scatter plot using the origin Code.
Now I am able to successfully save the created plot and also load it into a new script, which opens the Plot in Qt5 as well. **But somehow the interactivity is gone, meaning I am not able to rotate over the axes and flip the plot anymore.**

I was unable to find any guidance to that issue or find any person with a similar problem. Do you guys have any idea? I'll put the relevant part of my sample Code below:

""" First script """

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pickle

testdf = pd.DataFrame({"X" : x, "Y" : y, "Z" : z}) #x and y are the criteria, z the values, stored as lists

# Create 3d scatter plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=z, marker="o")
ax.set_xlabel("Initial Notional Cluster")
ax.set_ylabel("Laufzeit in Month Cluster")
ax.set_zlabel("Vol. Weighted Margin")
plt.show()

# Save the figure object as binary file
file = open(r"Init_Lfz_VolWeightedMargin.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(fig, file)
file.close()
```

""" Second script """

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figx = pickle.load(open(r"Init_Lfz_VolWeightedMargin.pkl", "rb"))
plt.show()
```

Any idea, why the interactivity is gone? According to the pickle library and other usercases, this shall not happen.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving interactive Matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348733/saving-interactive-matplotlib-figures)

Comment: @Joe No it doesn't. Same (unanswered) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511698/pickled-matplotlib-3d-lacks-interactive-functionality). The respective feature request is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10843).

Comment: @Joe Unfortunately it does not. I got the pickle functionality and so on from that post. However, as described, I am not ending up with an interactive GUI but only with a "picture" of the 3-D Scatter Plot without interactivity...

Comment: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31731945/7919597), also without success.

Comment: Maybe my first comment wasn't clear. You don't need to continue trying. It's currently not possible.