# How to save lambda function using numpy savez?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I know `savez_compressed` can save the functions generated from `scipy`. Is there any way to save `lambda` functions?

Attempt:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
xAxis = np.array([1,2,3,4])
data = np.array([1,3,5,6])

yAxisInterp = interp1d(xAxis, data, kind='linear')

np.savez_compressed('myDataLambda.npz', yAxisInterp=yAxisInterp)
print('yAxisInterp is saved')

# Following command does not work
# ------------------------------
yAxisLambda = lambda x : x

np.savez_compressed('myData.npz', yAxisLambda=yAxisLambda)
print('yAxisLambda is saved')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to pickle a python function (or otherwise serialize its code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pickle-a-python-function-or-otherwise-serialize-its-cod)

Comment: Actually, I searched some packages that can save the function, but I want to ask is there any options for np.save?

Comment: `yAxisInterp` is not a function.  It an object of class `interp1d` with a `__call__`.  `pickle.dumps(yAxisInterp)` works as does the `loads`.  Presumably it's saving the attributes which you can see with `vars(yAxisInterp)`.

Comment: I can `pickle` a function, but not a `lambda`.  That means I can also `np.save` it.  But the `load` has to `allow_pickle`, and the retrieved function will be embedded in an 0d object dtype array.

Comment: I think `lambda` function has a different behavior for python. Thank you for your support @hpaulj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `numpy.savez` does **not** save the functions in `scipy`, it saves *`numpy.ndarray` objects*, which are *returned* from those `scipy` functions.

That is, when you do:

```
yAxisInterp = interp1d(xAxis, data, kind='linear')
```

You've created an array, and that is what you are saving when you do:

```
np.savez_compressed('myDataLambda.npz', yAxisInterp=yAxisInterp)
```

You **are not saving the function**.

So no, you *cannot save functions, any functions, with `numpy.savez`* (and related methods).

Comment: `yAxisInterp` is not an array.  It's an instance of a scipy class.  I can `save` a function, or anything that can be `pickled`.  A `lambda` cannot be pickled.